# JQuery: Trying to validate input field inside of Custom WordPress field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, required

Having an issue trying to validate a custom field I created inside of The Events Calendar for WordPress where I have a number of custom fields in my Event page / post. It uses the standard post-new.php or post.php and I want to be able to validate against some of these custom fields. However, there's no ID's in these fields. Only name elements like this:

```
<input type="text" name="_ecp_custom_3" value="">
```

So I'm trying this script out:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#title').attr('required', true);
    $("[name='_ecp_custom_3']").attr("required", true);
});
```

The #title one works great but the custom one comes back with an error saying:

> Parsing Error: Unexpected token _ecp_custom_3

So how can I get this field to validate using the name element instead of the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine for me

So,Try to replace

```
$("[name='_ecp_custom_3']").attr("required", true);
```

with :

```
$('[name="_ecp_custom_3"]').attr('required', true);
```

so ,Sometimes a problem appears with double quotes jquery

Comment: Yes, it seems that  $('[name="_ecp_custom_3"]').attr("required", true); did work but only for text input fields. Still have issues getting checkboxes and select menus to work, but I'll post those issues later. Thank you.